# IgnoreCollision while Dodging & Colliding

Tags: unity, collision-detection, 3d

I'm working on a mechanic to allow the player to dodge through enemies. However I'm running into the issue where the player is only able to dodge through enemies while their *already dodging* when they collide with the enemy.

I want this to work both ways, as in, when their colliding with the enemy, they should be able to dodge through then.

Here's what I've been trying:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {

    //    STOP ENEMY FROM MOVING/PUSHING
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        Debug.Log("Collided with: " + col.gameObject.name);
        target = col.gameObject;
        target.GetComponent<ZombieController>().mRigidbody.isKinematic = true;

        //    IGNORE DODGING COLLISION WHEN ALREADY COLLIDED
        if (isDodging) Physics.IgnoreCollision(col.collider, GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
    }

    /*    IGNORE DODGING COLLISION
    if (isDodging && col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(col.collider, GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
    }*/

}
```

It just doesn't seem to work when the player has already collided with the enemy. Hopefully all that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be prepared to avoid collision when the player is in dodging state even it it's not in collision / `OnCollision()`. Put a block like below on the `Update()`:

```
if (isDodging)
{
    Physics.IgnoreCollision(GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").GetComponent<Collider>(),
                            GetComponent<Collider>(),
                            true);
}
```